# Fabrik security issue: input tag attributes expose database table prefix

Tags: security, form, fabrik

In the generated HTML for the input field, the `id` and `name` attributes shows the Joomla database table prefix.

Exposing the database prefix is a security concern.

Is there a way to prevent this?

```
<input type="text"
       id="jos75_customers___full_name"
       name="jos75_customers___full_name"
       size="60"
       maxlength="255"
       class="input-block-level form-control fabrikinput inputbox text"
       placeholder="Full Name"
       value=""
>
```

Comment: I usually use a custom table prefix - if use one at all - for the tables of the database that will be used by fabrik. There is no need to use the Joomla table prefix for those tables. It will also help having all those tables "grouped" and distinguished easier, therefore easier to work with them, when using database tools (like PHPMyAdmin).